# Appium Test Connection Refused

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

I'm trying to run this simple test on Appium on an android phone that's supposed to open a calculator  application but I keep getting errors.

This is the code I've written :

```
package appiumTests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class CalculatorTest {

static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        openCalculator();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void openCalculator() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability("devicename", "Galaxy A51");
    cap.setCapability("udid", "R58N4211WGA");
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
    cap.setCapability("appActivities", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap);
    
    
    System.out.println("APPLICATION STARTED...");
    
}
```

}

[And these are the errors I'm getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbgry.png)

Comment: did you start the appium server?

Comment: Yes I did, still unable to create a new remote session

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your appium server is started with default port (4723)
2. `udid`/`deviceName` use either of them , preferably not both
3. Capability is written wrongb replace with correct one already mentioned one

> appActivities
>
> appActivity